# What's the difference between Levenshtein distance and the Wagner-Fischer algorithm

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, levenshtein-distance, edit-distance

The Levenshtein distance is a string metric for measuring the difference between two sequences. 
The Wagner–Fischer algorithm is a dynamic programming algorithm that computes the edit distance between two strings of characters.

Both using a matrix, and I don't see the difference? 
Is the difference the backtracking or is there no further difference by the fact that one is the "literature" and the other one is the programming?

Also I am just writing on a thesis, and I am not sure how to divide it- should I first get into explaining the Levenshtein distance first and afterwards the Wagner-Fisher algorithm or doing both in one? I got kinda confused here.

Answer (score 10):

You actually answer the question yourself in the first paragraph.
In the second paragraph you mix them up a bit.

Levenshtein distance is an edit distance metric named after [Vladimir Levenshtein](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vladimir_Levenshtein) who considered this distance in 1965 and have nothing to do with the dynamic programming "matrix". And the [Wagner–Fischer algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wagner%E2%80%93Fischer_algorithm) is a dynamic programming algorithm that computes the edit distance between two strings of characters.

However, the Levenshtein distance is normally computed using dynamic programming if what you need is a general purpose computation, that is, calculate the edit distance between two random input strings. But Levenshtein distance can also be used in a spell checker, when you compare one string with a dictionary. In cases like this its normally to slow to use a general purpose computation,and something like a  [Levenshtein Automaton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_automaton) can provide linear time to get **all** spelling suggestions. Btw, this is also used in the fuzzy search in [Lucene since version 4](http://blog.mikemccandless.com/2011/03/lucenes-fuzzyquery-is-100-times-faster.html).

About your thesis, well I think it depends. If its about the actual Levenshtein metric then I think thats where you should start, and if its about dynamic programming you should start with Wagner-Fischer. Anyway, thats my two cents about it. And good luck with you thesis.

Answer (score 8):

Indeed, they are closely related, but they are not the same thing. The Levenshtein distance is a concept that is defined by a mathematical formula. However, trying to compute the Levenshtein distance by implementing the recursive formula directly will be horrendously slow. The Wagner-Fischer is a dynamic programming algorithm to compute it efficiently.